# Codehaus and Jackson ObjectMappers serialisations differences for nested object

Tags: java, serialization, objectmapper

Recently I had to update `ObjectMapper` dependencies in my project and I faced strange behaviour of ObjectMapper serialization for nested objects, namely, for object `PostUrl` and legacy `codehaus` dependency serialization works correctly, from object PostUrl with structure:
[image: PostUrl]

I receive serialization results as:

```
{
  "url": "https://example.com/",
  "params": [
    {
      "key": "methodData",
      "value": "value"
    }
  ]
}
```

Problem is that for the new `Jackson` `ObjectMapper` and the same input object `PostUrl` serialization returns:

```
{
  "url": "https://example.com/",
  "params": [
    {
      "methodData": "value"
    }
  ]
}
```

My object `PostUrl` structure looks like the below:

```
public class PostUrl {

    private String url;
    private List<SimpleEntry<String, String>> params = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>> getParams() {
        return params;
    }

    public void setParams(List<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>> params) {
        this.params = params;
    }
}
```

My `ObjectMapper` configuration looks like this:

```
objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule())
```

I am confused why the new Jackson cannot handle nested objects as the previous version did. I tried to attach `@JsonProperty` on the field to point to the correct field but it didn't bring a desirable effect. I assume that maybe I need to register some module or attach additional config for my `ObjectMapper` but till now I didn't find out what is the root cause. I will be grateful for suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Cheers!

Comment: (personally: i prefer new output :), root cause obviously: jackson-upgrade :), how to resolve/workaround: tried "custom entry" (not extending Map.Entry...)?

Comment: The new `ObjectMapper` probably does this because you use a class that implements `Map.Entry`. Try creating a separate class with properties `key` and `value` instead. If you're using Java 17 that can as simple as `public record Param (String key, String value) {}`.

Comment: If it was my personal project perhaps I would use a new way of serialization. In contrast, the serialization of the object in the new approach must be identical to the previous one because of the many dependencies that will use it. At the same time, I would not want to expose myself to potential backward compatibility problems. Ahh, the charms of legacy. It's java 11 under the hood @RobSpoor